# How can I plot the voltage across any component by Matlab?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, passive-networks, matlab, simulink

I want to ask how can I plot the voltage across any component by Matlab?

I have a simple RLC circuit and I want to plot the voltage across the 3 components and I didn't use Matlab before. I found the transfer function here in the site but still can't plot the voltage.

And the voltage source I will use is cosine source but I can't find it in the simulink also.

So this is what I made:

```
>> L = 0.047;
>> R = 220;
>> C = 0.000001;
>> Num = 1 ;
>> Denum = [L*C R*C 1 ];
>> G = tf(Num , Denum)
```

Comment: Are you confusing MATLAB and SPICE? http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/

Comment: Your signal in frequency domain. To draw the output with respect to time, you need to solve the differential equation of your circuit. Matlab offers `ode45()` regarding this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in MATLAB is the following:

Make a Bode plot like this:

```
L = 0.047; R = 220; C = 0.000001; 
Num = 1 ; 
Denum = [L*C R*C 1 ]; 
G = tf(Num , Denum);
bode(G); grid on
```

[image]

Or get a time-domain response like that:

```
omega = 4e3;
t = linspace(0, 3*2*pi/omega)
u = sin(omega * t);
lsim(G,u,t); grid on
```

[image]

For everything else (voltages and currents for each component) you are better off with Spice. There is also a toolbox for Simulink called SimElectronics, but I'd still prefer Spice.

Comment: Minor mistake, the OP states "And the voltage source I will use is cosine source" but in your Matlab script, it is `sin()`.

Comment: @CroCro -  sin is shorthand for cosine with -pi/2 phase shift. :-)